# Running ffmpeg through .net wrapper and integrating continuous text output to program

Tags: .net, vb.net, ffmpeg, wrapper

I want to build a simple program that uses ffmpeg to encode webm videos. For some reason it refuses to work with ffmpeg.

When I'm running this, the program will instantly display the "completed" messagebox and then nothing happens. What am I doing wrong? **Running the same code for youtube-dl works.**

```
Dim currentMesssage As String
Dim WithEvents P As Process
Dim WithEvents UpdateTimer As New Timer
Dim PThread As Threading.Thread

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If boxfilename.Text <> "" AndAlso IO.File.Exists(pathTodownloadto & boxfilename.Text & ".webm") = False Then
        P = New Process
        P.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        P.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        P.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
        P.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
        P.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Users\myname\Downloads\video stuff\ffmpeg.exe"
        P.StartInfo.Arguments = "-i 1.mp4 -c:v libvpx -b:v 1M -c:a libvorbis NewVideo.webm" '
        PThread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf RunProcess)

        UpdateTimer.Start()
        PThread.Start()
    Else
        MsgBox("Filename is either empty or file already exists.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
    End If
End Sub

Sub RunProcess()
    P.Start()
    P.BeginOutputReadLine()
    P.BeginErrorReadLine()
    P.WaitForExit()
    MsgBox("Completed.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
End Sub

Sub DataReceived(sender As Object, e As DataReceivedEventArgs) Handles P.OutputDataReceived
    currentMesssage = e.Data
End Sub

Sub TimerTick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles UpdateTimer.Tick
    lblProgress.Text = currentMesssage
    lblProgress.Update()
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you run the exact same command via the cmd prompt and does that work as expected?

Comment: @Hursey Yeah, works perfectly in cmd.

Comment: And if you move the P.Start() line into Button1_Click instead of jumping off to a new thread.  BTW, seems odd to me you would have a 2nd thread calling p.WaitForExit()

Comment: Acts the same. I can even make the simplest version of it where I only have P.Start and then P.WaitForExit where it doesn't even try to read any outputs and it still just finishes instantly without doing anything.

The reason for running WaitForExit in a seperate thread is because the form will become unresponsive if it runs in the same thread as that function.